Is is possible to check for reciprocity by looking at the G matrix in the MNF form?
According to the reciprocity theorem, a linear circuit is reciprocal if the transfer impedance in one direction is equal to the transfer impedance in the opposite direction.
If a circuit is described using Z or Y parameters, it is trivial to check for reciprocity by simply checking if the Z or Y matrix is symmetric.
In Modified Nodal Analysis (MNA), a circuit is described by matrices, typically the G matrix (conductance matrix), the B and C matrices (which relate voltages to independent sources), and the D matrix (for dependent sources).
My question is, if the G matrix is symmetric, can I say that the circuit is symmetric? Otherwise, how can check for reciprocity using the circuit description in MNF form.

MNF is an acronym for what?

The conductance matrix G is symmetric if the determinant of G is unitary. The matrix G is reciprocal if g12=-g21.
